# Content Securiy Policy (CSP) for multi-tenant apps

Tags: security, http-headers, xss

Trying to set a decent CSP policy for a multi-tenant webapp.
Since users can add content themselves, whitelisting or blacklisting certain domains is impossible.

It is possible to white list the default src's the app itself is using, but for other resources, it must be a wildcard, for example -

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' trusted.com *.trusted.com ; img-src *; media-src *; script-src *; object-src *; font-src *; style-src *; frame-src *
```

I guess the actual question is - would it be efficient to set up such a CSP header versus not setting one at all?

Answer (score 1):

If your users can add their own javascript as content by design, your application is vulnerable to XSS anyway. If they can't, then you should remove `script-src *` and replace maybe with `self`. This would help prevent some XSS attacks which should probably be your most important concern.

The same applies to `object-src`, does that need to be `*` too? It shouldn't be. The rest of the * values are I think present less risk, modern browsers will not normally run javascript from those.

The third thing that comes to mind is clickjacking. Do these pages ever have to be displayed in a frame? If no, then it's easy, you could set `frame-ancestors` to `none`, or `self` if you use iframes on your own origin. If your users do want to embed their page in an iframe, you could for exmaple have them register their origin when they want to have the iframe, and your application could dynamically generate a suitable `frame-ancestors` csp based on the origin of the current request.

Comment: Thanks for the insights!

First off - yeah, users can add their own JS code by design from different sources. (like custom code or external embeds that are using JS)

The object-src might be possible to avoid.

As for the frame ancestors - only need to allow frames from one specific domain (non-self), but that's no longer supported by most browsers, I'm afraid.